# how to run Qt project on iOS simulator and android simulator using QT Creator on mac Yosemite

Tags: android-emulator, ios-simulator, qt-creator, qt5.2

i am new with QT development. i am trying to run Qt sample project on iOS simulator and android emulator. 
it runs fine on real iPhone device but 
run on iOS simulator, Qt Creator gives me Application Output:

```
error loading  iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClientRun ended unexpectedly.
```

i have already installed Xcode 6.3.2 with command line developer tools and using QT Creator 3.0 with QT 5.2.0

when run on android emulator, the virtual device (**AVD for Nexus One By Google Android4.3.1** API level 18, CPU\ABI: ARMeabi-v7a ) i created in AVD Manager shown as **incompatible**

i have already given the paths of **sdk**, **ndk**, **jdk**, **ant** in QT Creator and i also have set the environment variable by creating a file named **.bash_profile**  in Home directory and puts these lines into this file

```
export JAVA_HOME= /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH= $PATH:/Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/AndroidSDK/tools
export PATH= $PATH:/Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/AndroidSDK/platform-tools
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT= /Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/android-ndk-r10e
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT= /Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/AndroidSDK
export ANDROID_HOME= “$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT”
```

i don't know either its a correct method to set environment variables or not.
i need your help to resolve this issue.Your effort will be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to download just only **Qt 5.5.0 for Android and iOS (Mac, 1.7 GB)** file from https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ and install it.
when it is completely installed, open up the terminal and enter

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/AndroidSDK
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

commands to set the environment for android development.

to set your android configuration just give these paths into the QTCreator

**JDK Location:**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**Android SDK Location:**

```
/Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/AndroidSDK
```

**Android NDK Location:**

```
/Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/android-ndk-r10e
```

**Ant executable:**

```
/Users/graphics/Desktop/Android/apache-ant-1.9.5/bin/ant
```

and must allow **Automatically create kits for Android tool chains**

this is how you can get your JDK location on mac :
just enter

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

in terminal.

Now create your virtual device as what you need every thing will be fine. no worries then. you can run your apps on both android emulator and iPhone simulator.

**Notice: give path of AndroidSDK, Android NDK, Ant executable location according to yours.
one more thing that i did, previously installed Xcode 6.3**